# Can't access one domain DNS not resolving

Tags: dns, ip

Problem:
Unable to access one domain amscymru.co.uk from certain locations only.

Desired Effect:
Connect to amscymru.co.uk normally

Desription:
There is some strange DNS problem that first appeared 2 days ago. Nothing has been changed in either domain's configuration nor server config. DNS does not resolve the domain name when using standard DNS for LAN router (192.168.0.1. No way to ping or tracert. Only when I use proxy or OpenDNS the website can be accessed from those machines. Problematic machines are located in Poland, Germany and UK. It seems that only certain networks can't access it.

Other domains can be accessed normally.
So far I wasn't able to find a reason behind it.

Have you ever come across something like this?

Comment: Must say I haven't. If you `nslookup` the domain, what is the output? Try this both on a machine with access and a machine without.
Also, try to `nslookup` with google's DNS (`nslookup amscymru.co.uk 8.8.8.8`), see if that changes the results.
One last thing, try to clear the DNS cache of the host before attempting to access the domain (`ipconfig /flushdns`). Does that change anything?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did all this before posting the question. I've been completely puzzled by this situation because I've never seen such behaviour. The problem is gone now however I'm unable to identify reason behind it. It seems like some there is some kind of system in place that restrict access to certain websites. This works regardless of ISP or networks but it is  selective at the same time. It simply does not allow DNS resolution for a website when accessed from certain networks/locations. All this lasted over 78h and now it is gone. No settings changes anywhere.